# stretch horizontally background image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I know this question was asked really often here, but none of the existing solutions hepled me. I have a horizontal empty block with a decorative ribbon which I have to stretch horizontally to fill the whole viewport.

```css
#upper-line {
 background: url(../images/upper-line.png) no-repeat;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 133px;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="upper-line"></div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that I have to stretch it only horizontally without the image changing vertical proportions or moving. I also want to use relative position in order to not to screw blocks that are above so I can't use enormous height value with absolute position. I'm trying to solve the problem with background-size property, but it the image just moves in the diagonal directions out of the block borders where it's not visible whenever i just don't increase height value.

```css
 background-size: 100% 100%;
```

This one didn't help me either - it stretches the image horizontally and keeps in proportions with navbar but squeezes it vertically and I have to keep the height- just horizontal stretching.
Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. Which property/values make a block without content, just with a background image appear on the window?

Comment: what does your image look like? It sounds like it's just a line, so you basically just want to extend the line to fill the whole container?

Comment: @deadfishli yes, that's a decorative line with some spirals I want to fill the whole container

Comment: Can you try out if the answer I added below solves your problem?

Comment: @deadfishli I tried today and it actually solved it! Thank you very much!

Comment: could you accept the answer below then to show that your problem was solved? That would be great,

Comment: @deadfishli I'd like to but my reputation here is too low to make an upvote:(

Comment: Normally you should see a checkmark that lets you "accept" and anwer as the one that helped you. Should be below the up/down vote buttons. That will give both you and me some reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, what you want to do is simply stretch the images to both sides, but keep the original height, right?

I assume you know the height of the image. For this example we'll use an image with a height of 15px.
Then you can just use:

```
background-size: 100% 15px;
```

As can be seen in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o3czsv9b/2/ the picture is stretched to the sides, but keeps it's height. That makes it look squished.

---

From what the name of your image it sounds like you're trying to place a picture of a line. If you want to extend something to the sides, sometimes

```
background-repeat-x: repeat;
background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
```

can give you the desired result. That depends on your image though.
Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o3czsv9b/1/